как можно отобразить word файл в streamlit средствами python
Каким образом можно на странице streamlit отобразить word файл, с соблюдением стилей, шрифтов, заголовков и пр.
Спасибо

Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

перевести его в формат html средствами самого офиса или сторонних конверторов?

сторонних, пожалуй

Отобразить документ Word можно только с помощью некоего объекта, имеющего полный доступ ко всем возможностям Microsoft Word и способного отобразить содержимое. В языках MS, например, такой объект - Word.Apllication и спецвиджеты. В Питоне есть библиотека (не помню какая), которая через Win32 API может достучаться до этого объекта, но счастья это не добавит, потому что должен быть ещё и объект, способный отобразить содержимое такого документа. Это не о Питон. Самое внятное, что можно предложить - просто запустить документ в его родной среде.
